# Launch program with option

Tags: windows

Hello in tutorial has been written:

> launch your agent with option /XML="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\OCS Inventory NG\Agent".

How Can I launch agent ( I have it ) with option?

I get the following error:

```
'/XML' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

Also agent is a exe program and I have .vbs script inside Plugin folder

Comment: It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread and to accept an answer. See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts) and/or [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) for guidance on how to merge your accounts.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the option on the command line when you start the agent.

Comment: User is obviously struggling to figure out how to do this.  You should provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

#### Open a command line.

<kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, type in `cmd`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

#### Launch the program with the option.

Copy and paste the line below onto the command line and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
C:\Program Files\OCS Inventory Agent\OCSInventory.exe /XML="C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\OCS Inventory NG\Agent"
```

This is assuming you have the `OCSInventory.exe` executable under Program Files (default location).